# Need to archive folders 3months old in unix server ny running a script. Is this possible?

Tags: shell, scripting, archive, php-ziparchive

I want folders created older than 3 months should be archived by running a script in unix server. Please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: you want to read man page of `find` command, and find out the option.

Comment: Do you mean "folders created more than 3 months ago", or "folders (recursively) containing only files and directories created more than 3 months ago"?